# Como fazer a junção de duas Arrays?

Tags: java, array, arraylist

Olá, Tenho o seguinte problema tenho um ArrayList que retorna varias pequenas arrays de duas posições

```
String[] temp = new String[2];
```

e tem o arrayList que salva adiciona varias "temp";

```
ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
while(rs.next()){
   if(rs.getString("texto") != null){
    temp[0] = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id"));
    temp[1] = rs.getString("texto");
    lista.add(temp);
   }else{
    temp[0] = String.valueOf(rs.getInt("id"));
    temp[1] = rs.getString("valor");
   }
}
```

Bom o `temp[0]` contém o ID de uma tabela meu desafio e pegar de dentro do ArrayList os valores e agrupalos por meio da posição do ID, assim ficariam apenas algumas arrays tipo a array `tempx[]` contem todos os `temp[1]` que tem `temp[0]`  com o mesmo valor. Que depois vai para outro Array List

**Tipo algo assim**

```
enquanto lista.get(a).temp[0] conter o mesmo identificador faça
tempx[i] = lista.get(i).temp[1]
i++;
Quando o lista.get(a).temp[0] mudar então  um novo arrayList deve receber essa nova array.
listaAtualizada.add(tempx);
```

Não tô muito bem das ideias hoje e tô sofrendo para fazer isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List tempA = new ArrayList();
             for(Object l: lista){
                 String[] arrayA = new String[2];
                 String[] ArrayB = (String[]) l;
                 int cont = 0;
                 for(Object l2:  lista){
                     String[] tw = (String[]) l2;
                     if(ArrayB[0].equalsIgnoreCase(tw[0])){
                         tempA.add(tw[1]);
                     }
                 }
                 tempX.add(tempA);
                 tempA = new ArrayList();
             }`

Isso gera muitos elementos duplicados então eu removo eles usando 

`// adiciona todos os elementos incluindos duplicadas
            Set<String> hs = new HashSet<>();
            hs.addAll(tempX);
            tempX.clear();
            tempX.addAll(hs);`